# Understanding whether an equation gives 4D or 3D surface

Tags: calculus, surfaces

Consider the following surfaces
S1: xyz=10 and S2: z=x^2+y^2

I cannot understand whether S1 and S2 are three dimensional or 4 dimensional.

S1 seems to be 4 dimensional, as I can consider x, y and z as independent variables. S2 seems to be 3 dimensional, as z is dependent on x and y.

However, my professor wrote G(x,y,z)=xyz and H(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-z while solving a problem related to these surfaces.

Don't the functions G and H show that x,y,z are independent variables, so the function is in 4D?

I am very confused, please help :(

Comment: The surfaces are two dimensional in three dimensional space

Comment: @jgon that's even more confusing...

Comment: I was worried it might be, but I don't have time to write a proper explanation right now, so I settled for at least putting down the answer

Comment: For S1, you can write $z = 10/{xy}$ and then you have $z$ dependent on $x$ and $y$ - so why do you think that the dimensions are different between S1 and S2?

Comment: @NickD you're right, but how can my professor write G(x,y,z)=xyz then? Doesn't G show that x,y,z are independent?

Comment: You might want to read up on _level surfaces_ of a function.

Answer (score 2):

I'll expand on my comment.

Let's be a little more careful about what $S_1$ and $S_2$ are.
Let's start with $S_1$
$$S_1=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb{R}^3 : xyz=10\}$$

So we can see that $S_1$ is a subset of 3-dimensional space ($\Bbb{R}^3)$ cut out by a single equation/condition $xyz=10$. Thus we have three independent variables on which we impose one constraint, so $S_1$ is a 2-dimensional subset of 3-dimensional space.

Similarly 
$$S_2=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb{R}^3:z=x^2+y^2\}$$
is also a subset of 3-dimensional space cut out by a single equation, so $S_2$ is 2-dimensional.

The confusion you seem to be having with respect to the functions is that
$x$, $y$, and $z$ are independent variables in $\Bbb{R}^3$, but not on $S_1$ or $S_2$ (since we imposed constraints on the variables to define the surfaces).

Not sure how you got to 4-dimensional space, or four independent variables though.